# Word citation manager and footnotes

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to use the Word citation manager on the Mac version of Word in Office 365 to do Chicago-style footnote citations (mostly because I don't want to have to deal with manually formatting those citations).

Currently, you can easily do parenthetical citations, e.g. (Smith, 2000). But I want to do something like this.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Smith, John. 2000. *Title blah blah*. 15 October. https://www.foobar.com/blah/bar/foo/blah.

---

Is there any way to do this in Word?